# PostgreSQL JSON aggregation on multiple groups

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregation

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/157ad/3

Is it possible to group by on multiple columns and then put the results on that aggregate in to a table.

I am trying to ask the database to tell me to find all the shipments and for each shipment what are the containers belonging to that shipment and what are the locations each shipment goes to. I am able to do this for one grouping, but I can't figure out for two group by clauses. Is it possible to ask this question in one single sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    s.shipmentName,
    array_agg(distinct sc.pk_shipmentContainerId) as container,
    array_agg(distinct l.locationName) as location
from
    shipment s
    inner join
    shipmentContainer sc on s.pk_shipmentId = sc.fk_shipmentId
    inner join
    shipmentMove sm on s.pk_shipmentId = sm.fk_shipmentId
    inner join
    location l on sm.fk_locationId = l.pk_locationId
group by s.pk_shipmentId, 1
order by s.pk_shipmentId
;
            shipmentname             |   container   |                       location                        
-------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 1.shipment of bananas - Loc 1,2,3,4 | {1,2,3}       | {"Location 1","Location 2","Location 3","Location 4"}
 2.shipment of apples Loc 1,2,3,4    | {4}           | {"Location 1","Location 2","Location 3","Location 4"}
 3.more bananas Loc 1,2,4,5          | {5,6,7,8,9}   | {"Location 1","Location 2","Location 4","Location 5"}
 5.lots of pants Loc 5,3,2,1         | {10,11,12,13} | {"Location 1","Location 2","Location 3","Location 5"}
```